# I'm unable to get heatmap.js to work even for a simple heatmap

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I'm a JavaScript newbie and I am trying to use the [open source heatmap.js framework (by Patrick Wied)](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) to create a heatmap, but it doesn't show up even for the most basic of heatmaps. Here is the test code that I am using.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Heatmap Test Code</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="heatMap" width = "1024" height = "742" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/heatmap.js">

var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
container: document.getElementById('heatMap')
});


var testData = {
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        data: [{x: 807, y: 583, count: 65}, {x: 597, y: 285, count: 51}, {x: 217, y: 449, count: 73}, {x: 377, y: 656, count: 58}, {x: 467, y: 509, count: 47}, {x: 487, y: 164, count: 46}, {x: 247, y: 194, count: 35}]
};

heatmapInstance.setData(testData);  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please would someone show me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any javascript error?

Comment: No there are no JS errors reported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few small mistakes:

1. You need to put a wrapper element around your canvas and set that as the `container`.
2. You also should put the external script and the inline script in separate `script` tags.
3. The value of the data points should be called `value` not `count`

Leading to:

```
...
<body>
    <div id='container' style='position: relative; height: 742px'>
        <canvas id="heatMap" width = "1024" height = "742" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/heatmap.js"> </script>
    <script>
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
        container: document.getElementById('container')
    });
    ...
```

Minimal working sample: http://jsbin.com/latepa

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I have done everything exactly as you suggested and I am still not seeing anything.

Comment: Did you look at (code+html of) the jsbin I posted? Your sample works there. I think I highlighted all the changes in my answer, but I might have missed something. Hold on, I just remember one more change I made

Comment: I'm looking at your jsbin code now. Your src refers to heatmap.min.js at Patrick's site. The Div id is heatMap (instead of container, but I changed those so that they map onto each other), and you also put the last script (var heatmapInstance plus data, etc.) after the </body> tag. It's exciting to me that you have got it working!!! It means that I'm close on this side :) Thanks for your effort